# Is possible find a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology

Is possible find a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$? If is possible, I think we can make $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$ with $f(0)$ out of radius $n$ for every $n$ natural number, and consider $f(x) = ||x||^{-1} x$, so that when $x$ is close to zero, $f(x)$ is large. Any better suggestions?

Comment: No. $\Bbb R^n$ is contractible. $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. They are not homeomorphic. For each compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb R^n$, there is a compact $K^\ast$ such that $K\subset K^\ast$ and that $\mathbb R^n\setminus K^\ast$ is connected (take a closed ball large enough). This does not take place in $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$; just consider $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: grateful for your attention!